# HTML form button not deleting rows from sqlite database

Tags: python, html, sqlite, flask

I have built a forum in pythonanywhere using python and html, in which users can post information that gets inserted into a sqlite database. At the bottom of each post is a delete button that will delete the post that it's under from the database and refresh the page. Right now the delete button only refreshes the page while the post remains. I am wondering how to edit the code so that the post which the form button is attached to is deleted and the page is refreshed.

HTML Code snippet

```
{% for post in forumposts %}
<tr>
    <td>
    <h1>{{post[1]}}</h1>
    <h3>{{post[3]}}</h3>
    <p>{{post[2]}}</p>
    <p>{{post[6]}}</p>
    <img src="{{post[7]}}" alt="Wrong image link.">
    <p></p>
    <form action="{{ url_for('delete_post') }}" method=POST class=delete-post>
    <input type=hidden value="{{ postid }}"name=post_to_delete></input>
    <input type=submit></input>
    </form>
    </td>
</tr>
    {%endfor%}
</table>
```

Python Code snippet

```
@app.route('/delete', methods=['POST'])
def delete_post():
    db = connect_db()
    db.execute('DELETE FROM posts WHERE postid = ?', [request.form['post_to_delete']])
    db.commit()
    db.close()
    return redirect(url_for('forum'))
```

Comment: Are you getting any errors in your python console?

Comment: Do you know how would I view the python console on pythonanywhere?

Comment: No I don't. What does Google say?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got the code working.

HTML

```
{% for post in forumposts %}
<tr>
    <td>
    <h1>{{post[1]}}</h1>
    <h3>{{post[3]}}</h3>
    <p>{{post[2]}}</p>
    <p>{{post[6]}}</p>
    <img src="{{post[7]}}" alt="Wrong image link.">
    <p></p>
    <form action="{{ url_for('delete_post') }}" method=POST class=delete-post>
    <input type=hidden value={{post[0]}} name=post_to_delete></input>
    <input type=submit value=POST></input>
    </form>
    </td>
</tr>
    {%endfor%}
</table>
```

PYTHON

```
@app.route('/delete', methods=['POST'])
def delete_post():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        db = connect_db()
        db.execute('DELETE FROM posts WHERE postid = ?', (request.form['post_to_delete'],))
        db.commit()
        db.close()
        return redirect(url_for('forum'))
```

Hope this helps someone. :)